# Oracle database connection problem after cloning the server

Tags: oracle, connection, database-cloning

I just clone a server that hosts Oracle in order to make a linux test machine. But the sqlplus user/password@alias connection does not work on the cloned server.
I do not find what to change.
Thank you in advance

here are the configuration files of the source server:

*Hostname :*

[root@server1]# cat /etc/hosts

192.168.0.11 server1.domain.com server1

*Global name :*

select * from global_name ;

my_sid1.server1.domain.com

*listner.ora :*

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = server1)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = REGISTER))
    )
  )

sid_list_listener=(sid_list=
                        (sid_desc=
                                (global_name=server1)
                                (sid_name=my_sid1)
                                (oracle_home=/u01/app/oracle/product/12r1)
                        )
                  )

*tnsnames.ora :*

serv1.my_sid1=(description=
             (address=
                 (protocol=ipc)
                  (key=my_sid1))
             (address=
                 (protocol=tcp)
                 (host=server1)
                 (port=1521))
(connect_data=(service_name=my_sid1.server1.domain.com)(server=DEDICATED)))

on the cloned server, with the configuration below, I have the error message "ORA-12154: TNS: Could not resolve the connect identify specified"

*Hostname :*

[root@server2]# cat /etc/hosts

192.168.0.12 server2.domain.com server2

*listener.ora :*

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = server2)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = REGISTER))
    )
  )

sid_list_listener=(sid_list=
                        (sid_desc=
                                (global_name=server2)
                                (sid_name=my_sid2)
                                (oracle_home=/u01/app/oracle/product/12r1)
                        )
                  )

*tnsnames.ora*

server2.my_sid2=(description=
             (address=
                 (protocol=ipc)
                  (key=my_sid2))
             (address=
                 (protocol=tcp)
                 (host=server2)
                 (port=1521))
(connect_data=(service_name=my_sid1.server1.domain.com)(server=DEDICATED)))

I am trying to use the sqlplus command as follows but it does not work:

sqlplus user/password@my_sid2

Thinks

Answer (score 0):

When cloning a host, the instance name did not change. The easiest way to change addresses in `tnsnames.ora`  `listener.ora` files without changing the instance name.
**listener.ora**

```
    LISTENER =
      (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
        (DESCRIPTION =
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = server2)(PORT = 1521))
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = REGISTER))
        )
      )

    sid_list_listener=(sid_list=
                            (sid_desc=
                                    (global_name=server1)
                                    (sid_name=my_sid1)
                                    (oracle_home=/u01/app/oracle/product/12r1)
                            )
                      )
```

**tnsnames.ora**

```
server2.my_sid2=(description=
             (address=
                 (protocol=ipc)
                  (key=my_sid1))
             (address=
                 (protocol=tcp)
                 (host=server2)
                 (port=1521))
(connect_data=(service_name=my_sid1.server1.domain.com)(server=DEDICATED)))
```

After editing the `listener.ora`, you must restart the listener process  as an oracle user.

```
lsnrctl stop
lsnrctl start
```

try `sqlplus user/password@server2.my_sid2`

If you need to change the instance name, then you need to follow the instructions for changing the database name.
[Changing the DBID and Database Name](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-05B4733C-9EAA-438F-A2A4-4E84EB1E1E65.htm#SUTIL1544)

Comment: Thank you for your reply Dmitry. 
I will test this.